# how to use a dagger fragment viewmodel in injected dagger fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm using dagger2 for DI, and developing for a single activity. So I did inject a fragment when start main activity, and the fragment also inject this viewmodel. But the problem is occured when I inject a viewmodel in dagger fragment. If I don't use a constuctor @Inject in dagger fragment, ViewModel is working well But can't Inject at MainActivity. If I use a constuctor @Inject in dagger fragment, ViewModel is not working and got the error like this

```
A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
```

Should I give up one?

*MainActivity*

```
    @Inject
    lateinit var myFolderFragment:MyFolderFragment
```

*myFolderFragment:MyFolderFragment*

```
class MyFolderFragment  @Inject constructor(): DaggerFragment() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory : ViewModelProvider.Factory
    private val viewModel by viewModels<MyFolderViewModel> { viewModelFactory }

    private lateinit var binding : FragmentMyfolderBinding
    private var mActivity:Activity?=null

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        binding = FragmentMyfolderBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container, false).apply {
            viewmodel = viewModel
        }
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this.viewLifecycleOwner
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot inject dependencies into Fragment via it's constructor. Activities, BroadcastReceivers, Services, ContentProviders and Fragments require default constructor because OS creates instances of that classes using Reflection API.
In my opinion you have 3 ways to solve this :

way 1 (Hardest One) - Use [FragmentFactory](https://proandroiddev.com/android-fragments-fragmentfactory-ceec3cf7c959)

way 2 (Easy to Undestand) - Direct inject in `onCreateView` method, it will look like this

```
  override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        binding = FragmentMyfolderBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container, false).apply {
            (context as MyApplication).component.inject(this)
            viewmodel = viewModel
        }
        return binding.root
    }
```

way 3 (Less code) - Instead of `Dagger2` you can use [Hilt](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android) that will hide all magic that you you manually writing when use `way 2`